# "Vectorized" Matrix-Vector multiplication in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, linear-algebra

I have an $I$-indexed array $V = (V_i)_{i \in I}$ of (column) vectors $V_i$, which I want to multiply pointwise (along $i \in I$) by a matrix $M$. So I'm looking for a "vectorized" operation, wherein the individual operation is a multiplication of a matrix with a vector; that is

$W = (M V_i)_{i \in I}$

Is there a numpy way to do this?

`numpy.dot` unfortunately assumes that $V$ is a matrix, instead of an $I$-indexed family of vectors, which obviously fails.

---

So basically I want to "vectorize" the operation

```
W = [np.dot(M, V[i]) for i in range(N)]
```

Considering the 2D array V as a list (first index) of column vectors (second index).

If

```
shape(M) == (2, 2)
shape(V) == (N, 2)
```

Then

```
shape(W) == (N, 2)
```

Comment: can you post your equations as images? unfortunately markdown/latex equations dont render on SO.

Comment: also, could you provide some input numpy arrays and expected output

Comment: In `numpy`, `*` is point-wise or element-wise multiplication.  `@` is matrix multiplication - with a sum of products on a specific pair dimensions.  `np.dot` and `np.matmul` document how dimensions are paired.  `np.einsum` is a more general tool for specifying multliplication and sum axes.  For `*` multiplication, the rules of `broadcasting` apply (`broadcasting` is also used with addition and other operations.

Comment: Your use of vector and matrix may be vague.  `numpy` has arrays, which may be 1d, or 2d (or 0d or 3d etc).  `vector/matrix` are not "native" numpy terms.  A 2d matrix may be considered a "matrix", but "vector" may have shape (n,), or (n,1) or (1,n).

Comment: For clarity, an example with iterative calculation, often helps.

Comment: I mean them in the proper (mathematical) sense, ignoring the standard abusive terminology which can be vague (hence why "vectorize" is in quotes).

Comment: Which branch of mathematics?  Often posters expect `numpy` to behave just like linear algebra or MATLAB, with a distinction between row vectors and column vectors.

Comment: "indexed family of vectors"?  `numpy` can have a (n,) 1d array, a (n,1) shape which displays as a "column vector", and (1,n) which might be described as a "row vector.  A "matrix" could have a shape (n,m).  The (n,m) shape could also be thought of as `m` (n,1) shaped vectors.  Or `n` (1,m) shaped?  Maybe your Family is (m,n,1) shape?  A `matmul` of (m,1,n) and (n,1) produces a (m,1,1), with sum-of-products on the shared `n`.

Comment: What you are looking for is `(M@V.T).T`. updated my answer for the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### EDIT:

Based on your iterative example, it seems it can be done with a dot product with some transposes to match the shapes. This is the same as `(M@V.T).T` which is the transpose of M @ V.T.

```
# Step by step
    ((2,2) @ (5,2).T).T
->  ((2,2) @ (2,5)).T
->  (2,5).T
->  (5,2)
```

Code to prove this is as follows. Your iterative output results in a matrix `W` which is exactly equal to the `solutions` matrix.

```
M = np.random.random((2,2))
V = np.random.random((5,2))

# YOUR ITERATIVE SOLUTION (STACKED AS MATRIX)
W = np.stack([np.dot(M, V[i]) for i in range(5)])
print(W)

#array([[0.71663319, 0.84053871],
#       [0.28626354, 0.36282745],
#       [0.26865497, 0.55552295],
#       [0.40165606, 0.10177711],
#       [0.33950909, 0.54215385]])


# PROPOSED DOT PRODUCt
solution = (M@V.T).T           #<---------------
print(solution)

#array([[0.71663319, 0.84053871],
#       [0.28626354, 0.36282745],
#       [0.26865497, 0.55552295],
#       [0.40165606, 0.10177711],
#      [0.33950909, 0.54215385]])

np.allclose(W, solution) #compare the 2 matrices
```

```
True
```

---

IIUC, your ar elooking for a pointwise multiplication of a matrix `M` and vector `V` (with broadcasting).

The matrix here is `(3,3)`, while `V` is an array with 4 column vectors, each of which you want to independently multiply with the matrix while obeying broadcasting rules.

```
# Broadcasting Rules

 M ->     3, 3
 V ->  4, 1, 3   #V.T[:,None,:] 
----------------
 R ->  4, 3, 3
----------------
```

Code for this -

```
M = np.array([[1,1,1],
              [0,0,0],
              [1,1,1]])    #3,3 matrix M

V = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
              [1,2,3,4],   #4,3 indexed vector
              [1,2,3,4]])  #store 4 column vectors
                           


R = M * V.T[:,None,:]          #<--------------
R
```

```
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 2],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [3, 3, 3]],

       [[4, 4, 4],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [4, 4, 4]]])
```

**Post this if you have any aggregation, you can reduce the matrix with the required operations.**

Example, `Matrix M` * Column vector `[1,1,1]` results in -

```
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]],
```

while, `Matrix M` * Column vector `[4,4,4]` results in -

```
array([[[4, 4, 4],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [4, 4, 4]],
```

Comment: I think this is actually. I'll have a play with it to be sure, thanks

Comment: cool, if this is it, then basically numpy is all about exploiting broadcasting to fit your needs. check the updated `broadcasting rules` table (before the code section) for reference on how this is working.

Comment: Sorry, no the output $W$ is to be an $I$-indexed family of vectors, just as $V$ is. But I'll check out your broadcasting tips as they will probably help a lot.

Comment: could you give an example with actual shapes? like shape of M, number of column vectors and shape of each vector for V, and expected shape of the output?

Comment: Ok I'll add some info soon. Cheers

Comment: do add a note here in the comments so i can get notified and update my answer. thanks and cheers!

Comment: `W = [np.dot(M, V[i]) for i in range(N)]` is just a simple dot product itself. maybe with some axis shuffled. because dot products of 2 matrices can be seen as the dot product of a matrix with its column vectors. stacked. updated my answer for details

Answer (score 1):

With

```
shape(M) == (2, 2)
shape(V) == (N, 2)
```

and

```
W = [np.dot(M, V[i]) for i in range(N)]
```

`V[i]` is (2,), so `np.dot(M,V[i])` is (2,2) with(2,) => (2,) with sum-of-products on the last 2 of M.  `np.array(W)` is then (N,2) shape

For 2d `A,B`, `np.dot(A,B)` does sum-of-products with the last dimension of `A` and 2nd to the last of `B`.  You want the last dim of `M` with the last of `V`.

One way is:

```
np.dot(M,V.T).T    # (2,2) with (2,N) => (2,N) => (N,2)
(M@V.T).T           # with the matmul operator
```

Sometimes `einsum` makes the relation between axes clearer:

```
np.einsum('ij,nj->ni',M,V)
np.einsum('ij,jn->in',M,V.T).T      # with j in last/2nd last positions
```

Or switching the order of `V` and `M`:

```
V @ M.T           # 'nj,ji->ni'
```

Or treating the `N` dimension as a batch, we could make `V[:,:,None]` (N,2,1).  This could be thought of as N (2,1) "column vectors".

```
M @ V[:,:,None]       # (N,2,1)
np.einsum('ij,njk->nik', M, V[:,:,None])   # again j is in the last/2nd last slots
```

Numerically:

```
In [27]: M = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]); V = np.array([[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]])

In [28]: [M@V[i] for i in range(3)]
Out[28]: [array([ 5, 11]), array([ 8, 18]), array([11, 25])]

In [30]: (M@V.T).T
Out[30]: 
array([[ 5, 11],
       [ 8, 18],
       [11, 25]])

In [31]: V@M.T
Out[31]: 
array([[ 5, 11],
       [ 8, 18],
       [11, 25]])
```

Or the batched:

```
In [32]: M@V[:,:,None]
Out[32]: 
array([[[ 5],
        [11]],

       [[ 8],
        [18]],

       [[11],
        [25]]])
In [33]: np.squeeze(M@V[:,:,None])
Out[33]: 
array([[ 5, 11],
       [ 8, 18],
       [11, 25]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, `np.dot(M, V[i])` has shape `(2,)`, and I'm really not wanting to sum anything.